# xcassets what are the pixel sizes for Universal x1, x2, x3?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcasset

I used to import assets from the Sympli plug in which did this stuff for me. I have a new version of an asset that I need to replace and this time I don't have Sympli to help me out. So what resolutions of the picture do I need in Universal x1, x2, x3? I guess I really just need to know what x1 is and can do the math for the other 2.

Comment: The preferred app icon sizes are outlined in the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/). Also, as you drop the icons into your asset catalog, it will warn you if used the wrong size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your image is `50 x 50`:

@1x = 50 x 50

@2x = 100 x 100

@3x = 150 x 150

Basically: `@1x * 1`, `@2x * 2`, `@3x * 3` of your original image size.

Comment: I get the x1, x2, x3 part, I just don't know what size I'm supposed to put for Universal x1. Like for AppIcon it tells me like iPhone 29pt, iPhone Spotlight 40pt, iPhone App 60pt. Or can the size be whatever? Like I said I never had to do this before coz I just imported the designer's assets thru Sympli

Comment: No it can´t be whatever for the app icon for instead, Xcode will give you warnings. When Xcode states a size you should follow that state. Otherwise when you add a asset add 1x, 2x and 3x.

Comment: yea so since its not telling me anything for Universal x1, x2, x3, I put anything for x1, then x2 and x3 those values for x2, x3 yea?